# generalized matrix inequality for complex Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, positive-definite, hermitian-matrices, linear-matrix-inequality

Assume having a symmetric real matrix $A$ and a skew-symmetric matrix $\Delta = [0 1; -1, 0 ]$, such that the following generalized matrix inequality holds in the PSD sense:

$$\pm \frac{i}{2} \Delta\preceq A.$$

Given the fact that for $ \frac{i}{2} \Delta$ the eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2} = \pm 1/2$ and for $ -\frac{i}{2} \Delta$ the eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2} = \mp 1/2$, does this inequality imply:
$$\frac{1}{2}I \preceq A?$$
If yes (or no), then can you explain what is the difference between them? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by symmetric Hermitian? Do you mean that if A= [a,b; c,d] then b=c and are real?

Comment: @AnCar Sorry, A is actually real and symmetric in my problem. I will fix that now.

Comment: Ah ok. Well I posted an answer. The really interesting thing is that if you assume that A is real symmetric, it will never commute with $\Delta$ unless A is a multiple of the identity. This sort of suggest that something bad might happen when trying to transfer the positive definiteness since A and $\Delta$ will not be simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: To be a bit more precise with what I meant above. If A and $\Delta$ did commute, you would have that $(A+i/2\Delta)(A-i/2\Delta)=A^2-1/4 I$. So $A^2-1/4 I$ would be psd, meaning that the eigenvalues squared of A are bigger than 1/4.

Comment: @AnCar Thanks a lot. I understood the answer you provided. But I am not sure what was wrong with the argument that I made with the PSD inequalities that resulted in $1/2 I \leq A$? 
I understand that you say A and \Delta don't commute. But how did that violate any of the steps of the argument?

Comment: Did my next answer clarify?

Comment: @AnCar let me ask this way. When comparing matrices with PSD inequality, does the two matrix have to have the same diagonalization so that you can compare their eigenvalues directly? right? otherwise if they don't commute you have to add them and find the eigenvalue of the summed matrix as a whole and see if the eigenvalues are positive...

Comment: exactly. if they commute, you can simply do arithmetic directly on the eigenvalues. if they do not commute, you can't in general do this. the solution to your problem is a nice and simple example of when doing eigenvalue arithmetic directly goes wrong due to non-commutativity. You can also think of this geometrically. if two matrices stretch vectors in different directions (by stretch i mean the action on the eigenvectors), you can't simply add or subtract their contributions since they occur on non-parallel vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following family of matrices $A_t:=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & t \\ t & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Obviously this is Hermitian (even symmetric Hermitian if that is what you really meant).

It is clear that the characteristic poly is $P_t(\lambda)=\begin{vmatrix} 1-\lambda & t \\ t & 1-\lambda\end{vmatrix} = (1-\lambda)^2-t^2=\big((1-t)-\lambda\big)\big((1+t)-\lambda\big)$, so the eigenvalues are $\lambda=1\pm t$.

Now consider the characteristic polys for $A_t\pm\tfrac{i}{2}\Delta$, which we denote by $Q_t$.
We get $Q_t(\lambda)=\begin{vmatrix}1-\lambda & t\pm\tfrac{i}{2} \\ t\mp\tfrac{i}{2} & 1-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=(1-\lambda)^2-(t-\tfrac{i}{2})(t+\tfrac{i}{2})=\lambda^2-2\lambda+\tfrac{3}{4}-t^2$. The discriminant for this is $\delta=1+4t^2$, so the eigenvalues will be $1\pm \sqrt{t^2+\tfrac{1}{4}}$.

We want $A_t\pm\tfrac{i}{2}\Delta$ to be psd, so we need that $t^2\leq\tfrac{3}{4}$, i.e., that $t\in[-\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}]$. Note however that if we pick $t\in(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}]$, then $A_t$ will have an eigenvalue smaller than $\tfrac{1}{2}$, meaning that $A-\tfrac{1}{2}I$ is not psd.